# LLVM IR Documentation

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

"A global variable may be declared to reside in a target-specific numbered address space." What is meant by "target-specific"?

Comment: You are asking regarding C++, right?

Comment: Yes. In the LLVM IR Documentation the word "target" comes out a lot of times but I cannot understand what it refers to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target-specific means that it depends on the target platform, that is the operating system and processor architecture for which you are compiling.

Comment: Thank you. Now it makes sense.